# Function it() inside a promise is not invoked

Tags: javascript, protractor, karma-jasmine

I get a list of elements, some of them are not visible. I want to click those that are visible and then chceck if they have a new class.

```
var tabsExpandable = $$("my-nav-bar .my-nav-bar-column-item.expandable");

tabsExpandable.each(function (tab) {
    tab.isDisplayed()
        .then(function (isVisible) {
            if (!isVisible) {
                return "not visible";
            }

            tab.click();

            it("should expand a visible tab", function () {
                expect(tab.getAttribute("class")).toContain("expanded");
            });

        });
});
```

But the function `it("should expand...")` is not registered and therefore the handler is not invoked. How to fix this issue?

Comment: What's your unit of work that you're testing? If it's just the `click` handler is adding the `"expanded"` class, you should test just that, with no iteration...

Comment: It's angularjs. I've made a custom directives for handling this expandings

Comment: My point is, it looks like you're testing too much in a single test. Doesn't matter what the framework is, a unit test should test a single unit/action. Your code seems to test a number of things (all of the "expandable" options are acted upon, `isDisplayed` returns a promise of whether the tab is visible or not, `click` adds an `"expanded"` class to the tab).

Comment: I'm doing e2e testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the `it(...)` first

```
it("should expand a visible tab", function () {
    var tabsExpandable = $$("my-nav-bar .my-nav-bar-column-item.expandable");

    tabsExpandable.each(function (tab) {
        tab.isDisplayed()
            .then(function (isVisible) {
                if (!isVisible) {
                    return "not visible";
                }

                tab.click();
                expect(tab.getAttribute("class")).toContain("expanded");


            });
    });
});
```